# changedTouches:TouchList is not a property?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand why *changedTouches* is NOT an testable property of an event. For instance, if I listen to a touchstart event (via Chrome->inspect and simulate a mobile device), such as

```
 $(document).on('touchstart', function(event){
      console.log(event.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) //logs true
```

As expected.

Now, If I log the whole event, I can clearly see it has *originalEvent.changedTouches* but testing the property will fail

```
      console.log(event.originalEvent.hasOwnProperty('changedTouches')) //logs false
```

But I can list the *changedTouches* by doing

```
      console.log(event.originalEvent.changedTouches);

      /*
      logs:
      hangedTouches: TouchList(1)​​
      0: Touch { identifier: 0, screenX: 753, screenY: 746, … }​​
      length: 1
      */
```

Also I can test that both properties are objects

```
 console.log(typeof(event.originalEvent), typeof(event.originalEvent.changedTouches)); //logs object object
```

The question is, why can't I test this property with *hasOwnProperty*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

try:

```
console.log('changedTouches' in event.originalEvent)
```

Comment: "as opposed to inheriting it" yup makes sense, thanks